# Should I share the same api between the cms and the application?

Tags: node.js, backend

I have a big fog in my knowledge, I really **need** to understand this part since I've not seen any article on the internet explaining this part.
I would like to create a huge platform like Udemy. I already have built many back-end applications myself in restful API design architecture, API-only, and API-First.

What I'm unable to figure out is.. you know that always a hugely important platform like Google, or Facebook, Twitter, or all of those tech giants, they all of course use an API-based design to make it possible for any user to access his data from any device.
meaning that you can use Facebook from your mobile phone, desktop, web application, or even maybe from your smartwatch... all of that made easy with API based back-end.

You know all courses that we buy out there to learn for example Nodejs, Php or any other technology, they all show us that we can do crud operations like deleting all users through an end-point like this:

- HTTP_METHOD: DELETE
- URL: api.example.com/users

And we can use the same API to see a certain post by some user like this:

- HTTP_METHOD: GET
- URL: api.example.com/users/mehmet-adam/posts/1561

You see, we can use the same API to perform both tasks, with the difference of the authorization.
so for example, only the user with the role set to "admin" can use the /users route to delete all users, no user with the role set to "user" can perform this task via this route.

My question here splits into two main parts:

First:
Do you think that **really** Google or Facebook will have some stupid exposed (but protected) end-point to the whole internet that allows the authorized user to erase the entire database through an end-point like this:

- HTTP_METHOD: DELETE
- URL: api.facebook.com/users

Personally, I don't believe that this is the case, which is the reason why I'm asking this serious question to the Internet.

The second question:

Of course, Facebook, Amazon, Udemy,
I'm sure they have some kind of a CMS to perform tasks like statistics, managing users, seeing the server state, or anything like that, which brings me to ask the second question:

Where this CMS is usually stored? I mean how it's accessible?

In an online course that you'll buy, you'll see everyone making the CMS accessible through a route like this:

example.com/admin

This is how I always make my apps, but now I believe that it's impossible that Facebook will make their CMS accessible like this

facebook.com/administration_panel

I'm interested to hear (read) all of your answers, no matter how much they're long

And, as an extra request, please give me some good place where I can read about this topic.

Comment: You might want to look into API design, especially how you design a RESTful (resource-oriented) API. Most questions about endpoints, URL structures, security will be answered after some research in this area.

Comment: @Ixg, thanks, I've been building apps in rest design for one and a half year, I've completed two nodeJS courses (without specifying their names) they all pretend that they'll teach you REST design, and in deed they do, but they never explain these parts that are mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. Most likely they will not have these endpoints if they don’t make sense. There is no rule that you have to implement all CRUD operations for every ressource. For example, when you look at Swagger specs for common APIs, you will find that they often are read-only or allow only specific operations.
2. The vast majority of enterprise platforms are not monolithic. They are usually (distributed) “systems of systems”, e.g. in a microservices architecture. Each microservice is responsible for one particular task and will expose an API for just that. This can be combined with aggregations such as an API gateway or GraphQL. Also, there is usually not “the CMS” but multple decoupled administrative tools which serve just a specific purpose. This allows faster development of independent areas of the entire platform. I would suggest looking at Domain Driven Design and microservices in general if you want to learn more about partitioning your enterprise platform into managable parts. Each part can then have its own API fit for the particular purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much IXG, I know you'll not believe it, but you really helped me a lot!!
I am now following your advice and reading more and more about APIs. That's great!. much new stuff to me, like as you mentioned "microservices", that's new to me. Thanks again..

Comment: Glad I could help. :) If you feel that this solved your problem, feel free to mark the answer as the solution.